# Withdrawing Ether from Cryptsy to geth

Tags: ethereum, cryptsy

I am trying to withdraw Ethers from Cryptsy to geth account. Cryptsy says address, where I enter my account id, is invalid. Do I need to create a separate addresses besides running `geth account new` to create a new account?

[image]

[image]

Comment: they are not processing ether withdrawals , and not providing support, i have my ether withdrawal "pending" for 10 days.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a formatting issue.  Include "0x" at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! Edited the question with screenshots. I assume this is the problem with Cryptsy?

Comment: Ok, I removed my comment about the typo that has been fixed

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why that wouldn't work if Cryptsy is working properly.  I may try it myself tonight.  I've seen reddit comments verifying that people have been able to withdraw ether from Cryptsy about a week ago.

Comment: Saw that my deposit address had "0x" at the beginning.

Comment: I can confirm account id (address?) needs to be prefixed 0x